# Can I invert diff_assoc_array() by performing it twice?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, diff

Would running array_diff_assoc() twice on an array give me all non-unique entries?

```
$array3 = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
$array4 = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array3);
var_dump($array4);
```

Comment: What are the contents of array1 and array2?

Comment: Or you can always call `array_unique`.

Comment: AHHHggg!  I don't know who to give the answer to!

Comment: @Dani, array_unique on the result of array_diff_assoc(), right?  Do you know what's faster, off hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:

- **A** the set of entries in `$array1`, and
- **B** the set of entries in `$array2`,

**B** would be composed of:

- **B'**, all the entries in **B** that are in **A**, and
- **B''** all the entries in **B** that are not in **A**.

`$array3`, `diff_assoc_array($array1, $array2)`, would be the operation **A \ B**, which would reduces as follows:

- **(A \ B') ∩ (A \ B'')**
- **(A ∩ ¬B') ∩ A**
- **A ∩ ¬B'**.

`$array4`, `diff_assoc_array($array1, $array3)`, would be the operation **A \ (A ∩ ¬B')**, which reduces as follows:

- **A ∩ ¬(A ∩ ¬B')**
- **A ∩ (¬A ∪ B')**
- **A ∩ B**

Therefore yes, the final result would be the items common to both arrays.

Comment: The complement operator is `\‍` and not `/`.

Comment: @Ignacio, I don't know what all those symbols mean, at all.

Comment: I tried googling them and stuff....  If you explain it, then I'll give you the green badge of courage, of course.

Comment: @千里ちゃん: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Basic_operations
Note that I use **¬** prefix notation instead of **'** postfix notation to indicate the complement.

Comment: So the prefix just means they're complimentary, huh?  Nice link.  Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

Solved...

```
<?php
  $array1 = array(0, 1, 2);
  $array2 = array("00", "01", 2);
  $array3 = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
  $array4 = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array3);
  var_dump($array3);
  echo "<br><br>";
  var_dump($array4);
?>
```